# Cpufreq doesn't quite want to set my CPU frequency permanently

Tags: debian, cpu, cpu-frequency

I'm on debian using the package `cpufreq`. I have the `userspace` governor loaded and it works to apply it. I have used `intel_pstate=disabled` in my kernel line because otherwise `userspace` isn't possible to load.

`cpufreq-set -g userspace -c 0` is what I used to set governor (for all 4 cpus).

I'm trying `cpufreq-set -u 0.8GHz` and `cpufreq-set -f 0.8GHz` on all CPUs in order to limit the maximum frequency to 800MHz, but it just doesn't really work. When idle, the CPU stays at 0.8GHz. `cpufreq-info` reports just fine, saying:

```
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.49 GHz.
```

But as you can see, the current frequency is at the maximum the CPU allows. This happens only when the CPU is used and the computer isn't in idle but I don't really care about what it's doing, if I say 0.8GHz max. then it should be 0.8GHz max.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the whole output for `cpufreq-info` for a CPU, others look the same:

```
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.50 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.50 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: powersave, userspace, conservative, ondemand, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "userspace" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.49 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.50 GHz:5.45%, 2.20 GHz:9.91%, 2.00 GHz:3.50%, 1.80 GHz:4.13%, 1.60 GHz:4.42%, 1.40 GHz:6.70%, 1.20 GHz:12.07%, 1000 MHz:30.03%, 800 MHz:23.79%  (659099)
```

Comment: What's the output of https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/cpumode ? It's a script which I created for myself many years ago because NiH and I wanted to understand how it all worked ;-)